# How to allow a role to block other users?

Tags: 7, users, advertising

Looks like there still isn't a great [anti-spam solution for D7](http://drupal.org/node/1293186) ;-(

I already have flags for nodes and comments with automatic unpublish once enough users flag it.

I want to be able to give users of a certain role the permission to block other users and possibly unpublish any content of that user.

I don't see a permission for "block user". How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a specific "block user" perm. Out of the box there's only the *administer users* perm, which in turn grants the role the ability to add/edit/remove other users. If you want a *block user* permission, you could define your own *block user* permission, then grant your custom permission to whatever user/roles you want. Here's the basic recipe:

- Implement [`hook_permission`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7), and add the *block_user* permission there.
- Implement [`hook_menu_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7), and modify the `'access callback'` argument for the `user/%/cancel` and `user/%/cancel/confirm/%/%` menu items to point to your own custom access callback function. You might also need to change the `'page_arguments'` setting to point to your own form instead of the default, if the default user cancel form doesn't cut it for you. The default form called is [user_cancel_confirm_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_cancel_confirm_form/7).
- In your custom access callback, you can use [user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) to verify that the current user/role has access to the block user permission.

Before you embark on this, you might be interested in checking out:

- The `user/%/cancel` and `user/%/cancel/confirm/%/%` entries in the `menu_router` database table. It tells you what are the access callbacks and all other important details of these paths.
- The [`user_edit_cancel_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_edit_cancel_submit/7) function on the [user.pages.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/7) include file. This is the Form API `#submit` function that gets called when you hit the *Cancel* button on any user user's account.
- The different account cancellation methods exposed in user_cancel_methods(), user.pages.inc. There's four cancellation methods. I think *user_cancel_block* and *user_cancel_block_unpublish* are the safest methods.

Sample code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_permission.
 */
function rallen_permission() {
  $perms = array();
  $perms['block_user'] = array(
    'title' => t('Block user'),
    'description' => t('Disables accounts and hides their contents.'),
  );
  return $perms;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter.
 */
function rallen_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $target_paths = array(
    'user/%/cancel',
    'user/%/cancel/confirm/%/%',
  );
  foreach($target_paths as $menu_item) {
    $items[$menu_item]['access callback'] = 'rallen_block_user';
  }
}

/**
 * Custom access callback for blocking users.
 */
function rallen_block_user() {
  if(user_access('block_user')) {
    return TRUE;
  } else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you must do it by custom module.

For blocking user, use db api and just change *status* column (users table) value to 0.

Similar things is for unpublish selected user content. All you need is in *node* table.

So you need two UPDATE statement for this job. That's all.

BTW. Do you try [mollom](http://drupal.org/project/mollom/) for anti-spam? You can specify any form to work with mollom.
Maybe you can configure this module to work with logged in users.

Mollom has nice permission, e.g.: Bypass Mollom protection on forms, so you can choose which role may bypass spam checking or not. Then just try to find any *hook* declared by *Mollom* module that allow you to block user when spam is detected.

Comment: Mollom FTW! Great Module.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing code I'll probably add a user flag to the profile that is only visible to that special rule. When you flag a user it would fire a rule to block that user.